# Question regarding the acceptance of wire instructions

Tags: wire-transfer

If a bank receives a wire instruction with the correct routing number but an erroneous prior bank name (due to a merger) will the bank still send the wire transfer or reject it and ask for accurate instructions

Comment: My gut feeling is this answer would be bank (and even time) specific, so even if someone has experienced this exact scenario, their answer of yes or no may not be relevant to your current situation. I think you need to ask the bank in question to get an accurate answer.

Comment: Echo @TTT's gut feeling: especially about the time factor. For a (fairly) recent merger, instructions might be circulating from beforehand, and would (gut feeling) be more likely to be accepted. If the bank in question was the UK's [Westminster Bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westminster_Bank) which merged with National Westminster Bank (NatWest) 50 years ago, I suspect they'd be rejected (even though it was still a registered, although dormant, company until 2017).